# 3ware 9550SX on CentOS8

Tags: centos, 3ware

I'm trying to use a 3ware 9550SX controller on CentOS 8. `lspci` shows the controller, but `lsblk` doesn't list the exported drives. I've exported 2 drives, each as single drives, no RAID mode being used.

Do I have a chance to use the drives? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for that card was removed from RHEL 8 (the sources from which CentOS is built on).

Reference: [Considerations in adopting RHEL 8: 11.1. Removed hardware support](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/hardware-enablement_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8#removed-device-drivers_hardware-enablement)

This is also covered in the [CentOS 8 Release Notes](https://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS8.1905#head-6beb5b31c4db977ccd65d5b829120bc06b746f9b).  Those notes mention that the [CentOSPlus](https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/CentOSPlus) kernel contains these drivers, you can give that a shot.  It also points to a 3rd-party repository that has driver update disks available for the removed devices.

Personally, I would strongly consider replacing it with a supported card at the earliest opportunity.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I think I will do so as suggested and get a newer card. The reason I came to this question was to re-actictivate an old server, but in this case, if I want an up-to-date os, I should get rid of the old obsolete stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I can't change the hardware, so I grabbed a driver from elrepo.org. The following worked for me.

In Anaconda (the installer), enable networking then go to a terminal:

```
cd /run/install/repo
wget http://elrepo.reloumirrors.net/dud/el8/x86_64/dd-3w-sas-3.26.02.000-2.el8_1.elrepo.iso
```

You may have to select the specific driver for your hardware from the mirror.

Then reboot, and edit the grub config line by pressing Tab and add:

```
inst.dd=/dev/sda1
```

(or whatever the device is on your system). The installer should detect your disks then.